# Flutter - I want to pass variable from one class to another

Tags: flutter

I just want to pass the int and boolean from one class to another class. For that particular integer can be displayed in the app bar of the second page, background color needs to be changed based on boolean (True/false).

Comment: There are several similar questions already.

Comment: But I didn't get any relevant pieces of information from others answer.

Comment: You could link to answers you checked and explain what information is missing or what you try to do differently. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RS36gBEp8OI might give you some ideas how to do it.

Comment: Too broad yeah. We need an example of what you want and why the existing questions didn't work

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In navigator you can pass data or object which you want to send to other class.

For example,

```
// Data need to sent second screen
class Person {
  final String name;
  final String age;

  Person(this.name, this.age);
}

// Navigate to second screen with data
Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new SecondScreenWithData(person: new Person("Priyank","28"))));
```

In `SecondScreenWithData` class, you can get passed data as below.

```
class SecondScreenWithData extends StatelessWidget {
  // Declare a field that holds the Person data
  final Person person;

  // In the constructor, require a Person
  SecondScreenWithData({Key key, @required this.person}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Second Screen With Data"),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            // Display passed data from first screen
            new Text("Person Data  \nname: ${person.name} \nage: ${person.age}"),
            new RaisedButton(
              child: new Text("Go Back!"),
              onPressed: () {
                // Navigate back to first screen when tapped!
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }
            ),
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
```

Check full [Navigation Demo](https://github.com/1priyank1/flutter-demos/blob/master/navigation/lib/main.dart)

Comment: In the SecondScreenWithData shouldn't it be widget.person ?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches that work well. The first is by using

`Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen(dataFromFirst: 'Pass Data from First Screen to Second')),`

and retreive it from the Second Screen with `Navigator.pop(context, 'Pass Data from Second Screen to First Screen');`

Full Code here:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: FirstScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class FirstScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstScreenState createState() => _FirstScreenState();
}

class _FirstScreenState extends State<FirstScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            final result = await Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen(dataFromFirst: 'Data from First Screen')),
            );

            if (result != null) {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(
                  content: Text('Received result: $result'),
                ),
              );
            }
          },
          child: Text('Go to Second Screen'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String dataFromFirst;

  SecondScreen({required this.dataFromFirst});

  @override
  _SecondScreenState createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}

class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Second Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('Data from First Screen: ${widget.dataFromFirst}'),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, 'Data from Second Screen');
              },
              child: Text('Send Data to First Screen'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The second method is by using a static variable. The bellow code is using StatelessWidget so you will have to refresh the app with 'Hot Reload' or convert it into a StatefulWidget to see the changes.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Flutter Static Variables Example'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ClassA(),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            ClassB(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ClassA extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text('Class A'),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // Set the static variable in ClassB
              ClassB.sharedValue = 'Hello from Class A!';
            },
            child: Text('Set Value in Class B'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ClassB extends StatelessWidget {
  // Static variable to share values between classes
  static String sharedValue = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text('Class B'),
          Text('Shared Value: $sharedValue'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```