# How i can display data in form of list from cloud firestore and pass to another file in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i want to take data from cloud firestore and want to send into another file in flutter

i am using streambuilder for data retrieving but the list in not initialised globally

```
  class _DataState extends State<Data> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
       stream: Firestore.instance.collection('notification').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if(!snapshot.hasData){
            return new Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
                          child: new Center(
                            child: new Text(
                              "loading Data Please wait...",
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
          }
return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
           itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.documents[index];
      List<Book> books = [
      Book(ds['school_name'], ds['school_name'],'Rp 50.000', 'res/corel.jpg', 3.5, 123),
];
      }
);
        },
    );
  }
}
```

and the file in which i want to receive data is

```
final grid = CustomScrollView(
  primary: false,
  slivers: <Widget>[
    SliverPadding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      sliver: SliverGrid.count(
        childAspectRatio: 2 / 3,
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        mainAxisSpacing: 20.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 20.0,
        children: books.map((book) => createTile(book)).toList(),
      ),
    )
  ],
);
```

The problem is that how i can use the books array in another file because it is local variable. is there is any other method for doing it same.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50702749/flutter-i-want-to-pass-variable-from-one-class-to-another/50704819#50704819) , you can use navigator to pass data or object to another class.

In your case, you can use the navigator like this:

```
class _DataState extends State<Data> {
    ........
    List<Book> books = [
      Book(ds['school_name'], ds['school_name'],'Rp 50.000', 'res/corel.jpg', 3.5, 123),];

    // Navigate to second screen with data
    Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new 
    SecondScreenWithData(book: books)));                                          
   ...                                                                              
}
```

The second class

```
class SecondScreenWithData extends StatelessWidget {
   // Declare a field that holds the Books data
   final List<book> book;
   ......
   // In the constructor, require a Book
   SecondScreenWithData({Key key, @required this.book}) : super(key: key);
   ......
   // To display your books
   children: <Widget>[
   // Display passed data from first screen, you can run a for if you have more than a book
  new Text("Book Data  \nschool name: ${book[0][0]} \nprice: ${book[0][2]}")] 
   ......   
}
```

[Here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/simple-ways-to-pass-to-and-share-data-with-widgets-pages-f8988534bd5b) you can find a tutorial which can help you with passing and sharing data.