# How do i access a varible from another class in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making my first flutter app.

it asks for some information then when you click a button it shows the information you entered on another page, I wanted to ask. How do I get a variable from another class?

so  I can use the information entered on another page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter - I want to pass variable from one class to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50702749/flutter-i-want-to-pass-variable-from-one-class-to-another)

Comment: how are you calling the other page?

Comment: Can you please add details on what you've tried so far?

Comment: you can pass the data when you call other screen and access that data on other screen by making a constructor of that second screen with a parameter

Comment: Please show us some code so we can see what you are trying to do and help you in an easy way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to pass some data while navigating to another page. If I'm not wrong You should define a variable in the destination like this:

```
class NewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int someInt;
  NewPage({Key key, this.someInt}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NewPageState createState() => _NewPageState();
}

class _NewPageState extends State<NewPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Container(child: Text("${widget.someInt}"),),
    );
  }
}
```

In the above code I passed `someInt` to NewPage class.
In the first page you should navigate like this:

```
Navigator.push(
context,
MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (context) => NewPage(someInt: 293,),
));
```

put above code in the `onPressed` and pass the data with constructor.